# How to delete django dynamic formset with java script - issue with index?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, formset

In my template i'm using a formset to add a "Raum"-form dynamic.

In each row of my table, there is a button "delete row", so that i can delete the row again.

the java script code is as far as i can say is working quite well...
Adding and saving the forms works fine.

Also deleting with the java script code works fine.
Even when i delete the last row of the table, saving the forms works fine.

But when f.e. i add 3 rows (rooms), row1-row2  and row3, and i delete row 1 or row 2, i can not save my forms, because i think in view.py the is_valid method = false...

maybe i have to update some kind of index of my forms??? and how ??

any help is really apprecheated...

html template for adding rooms with the table and forms:

```
   <table id="tableHeadToModify" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="hg-rot schrift-weiss">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Räume</th>
                    </tr>
                    {% for raum in raum_formset  %}
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ raum.name.label_tag }}</th>
                                <th>{{ raum.name.label_tag }}</th>
                            </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tableToModify">
                     {{raum_formset.management_form}}
                    {% for raum in raum_formset %}
                         <tr id="rowToClone">
                           <td> {{ raum.name }} </td>
                           <td><button type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
                         </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
        </table>
                 <button id="add-form" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md">add room</button>
```

```
 <script>

    let container = document.querySelector("#form-container")
    let addButton = document.querySelector("#add-form")
    let totalForms = document.querySelector("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS")
    let rowCount = document.getElementById('tableToModify').rows.length-1;

    addButton.addEventListener('click', addForm)

    function addForm(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        let formRegex = RegExp(`form-(\\d){1}-`,'g')

        rowCount = document.getElementById('tableToModify').rows.length-1;

        var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone"); // find row to copy
        var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to
        var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too

        table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table

        rowCount++
        clone.innerHTML = clone.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, `form-${rowCount}-`)
        totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${rowCount+1}`)
    }

    function deleteRow(r) {

      var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
      var total = parseInt($('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
      if (total > 1) {
          var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
          document.getElementById("tableHeadToModify").deleteRow(i);
          totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${rowCount}`)
        }
      }
    }
```

```
views.py
```

```
    formset_raum = RaumFormSet(data=self.request.POST)

    #wenn die Eingabe der Formen passt
    if kunde_form.is_valid() and angebot_form.is_valid() \
            and objekt_form.is_valid() \
            and formset_raum.is_valid():<--- this isn't valid
```

Comment: is your issue solved ?

Comment: i made a workaround.

in the forms.py i added 
can_delete=True

so you can render in my case raum.DELETE in the template.
See documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/